# Finding specific RGB color and auto clicking on it with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Im working on my first "real" project for python. It automates a click accuracy test. The goal is to find the red circles and automatically locate and click on it.

Im currently using pyautogui to take a screenshot, but im stuck on how to auto locate the RGB color I need.

```
def find_red_dot():
    print('STARTED TEST!')
    time.sleep(5)
    image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(# Find the color)
    print('FOUND THE RED DOT')

def click_on_dot():
    pyautogui.moveTo(# Location where the color is found)
    pyautogui.click()
```

Cant seem to figure out how to get pyautogui to find the rgb color, (255,0,58)

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? There's a section called "Pixel Matching." https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Answer (score 1):

i get have a way, its not good but maybe you can try:
by making a 1 pixel picture with color you want, and `pyautogui.locateallonscreen()` using that picture, pyautogui will search for every single pixel for that single color picture, which means the color.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but this will work;

```
import pyautogui as py
py.displayMousePosition()
```

Run in your IDE and it'll display in the terminal the screen position and the RGB value of any pixel.